# Passing JSON to array

Tags: python, json, numpy, dictionary

Trying to write a cosine similarity method that parses the following JSON and calculates the similarity between 2 users:

```
{
"Rajan":
{
    "Inception": 2.5,
    "Pulp Fiction": 3.5,
    "Anger Management": 3.0,
    "Fracture": 3.5,
    "Serendipity": 2.5,
    "Jerry Maguire": 3.0
},
"Rinku":
{
    "Inception": 3.0,
    "Pulp Fiction": 3.5,
    "Anger Management": 1.5,
    "Fracture": 5.0,
    "Jerry Maguire": 3.0,
    "Serendipity": 3.5
}
}
```

However, I'm having trouble parsing the JSON diction to array to carry out cosine similarity.

```
import os
from sys import platform
import json
import numpy as np


def check_user_exist(self, dataset, user1, user2, algorithm):
    # check user in dataset
    if user1 not in dataset: raise Exception('User ' + user1 + ' not in dataset.')
    if user2 not in dataset: raise Exception('User ' + user2 + ' not in dataset.')

    rated_by_both = {item: 1 for item in dataset[user1] if item in dataset[user2]}
    if len(rated_by_both) == 0: return 0
    num_ratings = len(rated_by_both)

    if algorithm == 'euclidean_distance':
        return self.euclidean_distance(dataset, user1, user2)
    elif algorithm == 'cosine_similarity':
        return self.cosine_similarity(dataset, user1, user2)

def cosine_similarity(self, dataset, user1, user2):
    """ return cosine similarity between two lists """
    for item in dataset[user1]:
        print dataset[user1][item]
    array_user1 = np.array(item for item in dataset[user1][item])
    array_user2 = np.array(item for item in dataset[user2])
    dot_product = np.dot(array_user1, array_user2)
    norm_user1 = np.linalg.norm(array_user1)
    norm_user2 = np.linalg.norm(array_user2)
    return dot_product / (norm_user1 * norm_user2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
path = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())

filename = path + '/data_files/movie_ratings.json' \
    if platform == 'linux' or platform == 'linux2' \
    else path + '\\data_files\\movie_ratings.json'

with open(filename, 'r') as f: data = json.loads(f.read())
user1 = 'Rajan'
user2 = 'Rinku'
measures = Similarity()
print('\nCosine similarity:')
print(measures.check_user_exist(data, user1, user2, "cosine_similarity"))
```

Currently being thrown the following error at `np.array(item for item in dataset[user1][item])` in my cosine_similarity method:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

During debugging with `for item in dataset[user1]: print dataset[user1][item]` I get the following output:

```
3.5
3.0
3.0
3.5
2.5
2.5
```

Which is basically the movie ratings given by the first user. How do I parse the JSON dictionary into an array so that I can carry out a cosine similarity test?

Comment: Use `np.array(list(data['Rajan'].values()))` if you want an array with the  numeric values for one user.

Comment: highly recommend pandas to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use pandas, the overhead of accessing data is reduced to simple key lookups on a DataFrame. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def cosine_similarity(dataset, user1, user2):
    """ return cosine similarity between two lists """
    dot_product = np.dot(dataset[user1], dataset[user2])
    norm_user1 = np.linalg.norm(dataset[user1])
    norm_user2 = np.linalg.norm(dataset[user2])
    return dot_product / (norm_user1 * norm_user2)

data = {
    "Rajan": {
        "Inception": 2.5,
        "Pulp Fiction": 3.5,
        "Anger Management": 3.0,
        "Fracture": 3.5,
        "Serendipity": 2.5,
        "Jerry Maguire": 3.0
    },
    "Rinku": {
        "Inception": 3.0,
        "Pulp Fiction": 3.5,
        "Anger Management": 1.5,
        "Fracture": 5.0,
        "Jerry Maguire": 3.0,
        "Serendipity": 3.5
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sim = cosine_similarity(df, 'Rajan', 'Rinku')
print(sim)
```

Output:

```
0.9606463013980241
```

Answer (score 1):

`dataset[user1][item]` is a float according to your print statement. And you can not iterate a float. It should be

```py
np.array(item for item in dataset[user1])
```

Instead of

```py
np.array(item for item in dataset[user1][item])
```

In your `cosine_similarity` function at `array_user1 = np.array(item for item in dataset[user1][item])`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. adding a dependency on pandas in order to avoid this self-inflicted error is nuts (no matter how nice pandas is to use).

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in dataset[user1].keys():
    print dataset[user1][item]
```

Use .keys() for each key in dict